# UIImagePickerViewController camera preview black screen on iPhone 5 working fine on 4S

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iphone-5

In my application, I am taking images and uploading them to server. I first take image using UIImagePickerViewController then upload it to on the background thread, while it uploads, I take another image and upload it as well on separate thread, So basically taking and uploading multiple images without freezing the UI.It is working exceptionally well on iPhone 4S but on iPhone 5, the Camera screen goes black sometimes, sometimes there are many glitches when camera opened and I could not take the picture. It's driving me crazy why it is not working on iPhone 5. On stackoverflow, there are similar questions which says it is due to background threads or any UIKit processing on background, but the same code is working well on iPhone 4s. Both devices are on iOS 7, Can anyone help me with this?
I am uploading images on button action as

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),^{



            ImageUploadService *service = [[ImageUploadService alloc] init];
            service.delegate = self;
            [service uploadMultipartImage:compressDocumentImageData andFileName:uploadFileName andCompletionHandler:^(NSString *resut,NSError *error)
             {

             }];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (!isDocumentImageUploaded)
                {
                    [documentUploadView.uploadingActivity stopAnimating];
                    documentUploadView.imageUploadingLabel.text = @"Terms & Conditions document uploaded";
                    documentUploadView.uploadingDoneImage.hidden = NO;
                    isDocumentImageUploaded = YES;


                }
}
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: it looks like the image or other object is being released, what happened if you put everything under the main queue?

Comment: Well, it is working fine on iPhone 4s. I am using ARC, the problem is when I present UIImagePickerController, the camera preview screen goes black for some reason only in iPhone 5.

Comment: @RanaAsif Did you figure out ?